# How to dynamically call stored procedures without stopping console app?

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, visual-studio-2008, .net-4.0

We have a simple console application that essentially reads XML files and inserts many counters to a main table.

Once the console app downloads all files for the hour, it inserts all that raw data to a main staging table. Then the app invokes a series of stored procedures, which populate several other tables that, in turn, populate several reports. Once the console app completes for an hour, it *sleeps* for 5 minutes before it starts.

For now, we've only generated 5 reports from this data, so the current architecture is pretty straightforward: there are 5 methods that make standard calls to 5 relevant stored procedures that fill 5 tables.

The issue is that there will be tons more reports, which means that there will be tons more stored procedure calls. If I continue making the SP calls this way, that means I will either have to stop the app to update the EXE and DLL, or wait until I get the 5-min break between hours to update the EXE and DLL.

Is there a way to call stored procedures without having to modify the EXE? I was thinking of creating a table with all stored procedures, but that sounds very messy.

Comment: Seems like more of a design question, maybe Programmers?

Comment: You are better off modifying the EXE or else it will be a band aid fix.Store the stored procedure names in the app.config file as a list and in the console app read and loop through it.Update the config file when new store procedures are added.

Comment: There are many different ways you could approach this problem. A simple  design would be to, store the procedures that need to be executed into a table in the database then have the application query that table to determine what to execute, then the application would just need to check that table on every run it executes. This would allow you to add, remove, modify which procedures to run without breaking/stopping the process. This would be a more scalable approach then having to modify the code, like would be done as a band aide fix.

Comment: This sounds like it can be automated with some sort of Shell/Perl/Python script, with the appropiate call (and parameters) to the database executable. It would be more easy to help you if you specify: platform, database engine and maybe  the names of the SP's with some example of how you are calling them.

Comment: @LeonelAtencio please look at the tags on this question and see your questions about platform answered.

Comment: I have a similar process that runs a varying number of stored procedures. I use a table with each stored procedure name that I can update as necessary and have an outside procedure which loops through the table.

Comment: I was considering using a table with all the SPs that I need to run, but I was hoping for something more structured. I really didn't want to dump a bunch of stored procedures into a table.

Comment: @rbhatup If you come up with a solution that is "more structured" you will probably lock yourself into that solution, so if the problem changes in anyway you will have to redesign again. Putting the SPs into a table is flexible and scalable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using app.config temporarily to store the SP names, but eventually I'll store them to a table.

Thanks.